Delay between writes of two spi.xfer for sending data to DAC
I am using Raspberry pi 3 for sending data through a DAC through SPI communication. Right now I am using AD5686 which is connected to the raspberry pi using SPI communication SPI0 (SCLK to CLK of DAC, CE1 to SYNC of DAC, MOSI to DIN of DAC and MISO to SDO of DAC). Also there is this power pin which is used to power up the board which contains this DAC (AD5686). This should be on for the DAC to work. And there is this reset pin which is in the DAC, which should be set low for 30ns such that the DAC output is reset to zero before giving the data. And the DAC supports a maximum of 50Mhz so I used a clock of 40Mhz. The data I wanted to generate is sine wave which I am able to produce in lower frequencies around 500Hz. But I want to generate sine waves up to 10kHz. But if I am trying to generate 10kHz I am getting only 5 samples for one complete sine wave. Then I asked in the analog devices forum (engineer zone) they asked me to check the timings of each write operation, And I found that between each writes (updates) there is a delay of 20us for which the updating frequency will come around 50kHz which will give only 5 samples per sine wave (when I want to produce a sine wave of 10kHz repetition frequency). I will attach the code and the timing diagram. So I need to increase the update rate per second to the DAC such that I can get at least some 50 to 100 samples per sine wave for 10kHz repetition frequency. Can anyone help me with this?
import spidev
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math

# Define GPIO pins
SYNC_PIN = 7
RESET_PIN = 22
POWER_PIN = 13

# Define SPI settings
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 1)  # SPI bus 0, device 1
spi.mode = 0b10
spi.max_speed_hz = 40000000  # 40 MHz

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(SYNC_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(RESET_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(POWER_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

def power_up():
    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.HIGH) #powering up the board that contains DAC

def power_down():
    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.LOW)

def reset():
    GPIO.output(RESET_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.00004)  # Minimum of 40 ns for reset the DAC output to 0
    GPIO.output(RESET_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)

def write_and_update_dac_channel(channel, data):
    # Convert data to an integer
    data = int(data)

    # Construct the 24-bit shift register named as command word for writing to and updating DAC channel 0011 as command (first four bits) for writing and updating the DAC, Channel address as 0001 (5th to 8th bit) and balance 16 bit is the data we want to produce on DAC with the reference voltage of 4.096V
    command_word = (0b0011 << 20) | (channel << 16) | data

    # Send the command word over SPI
    GPIO.output(SYNC_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    spi.xfer2([command_word >> 16, (command_word >> 8) & 0xFF, command_word & 0xFF])
    GPIO.output(SYNC_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)

def generate_sine_wave():
    SINE_DC_OFFSET = 32768 # midscale
    SINE_AMPLITUDE = 32767 # amplitude from 2.048 to 4.096

    SINE_WAVE_STEPS = 100  # 100 quantisiation delay for one cycle
    STEP_DELAY_MICROS = 8.13 #micro second delay for one step

    sineWave = [0] * SINE_WAVE_STEPS

    for i in range(SINE_WAVE_STEPS):
        sineWave[i] = SINE_DC_OFFSET + SINE_AMPLITUDE * math.sin(i * 2 * math.pi / SINE_WAVE_STEPS)

    i = 0
    while True:
        write_and_update_dac_channel(0b0001, sineWave[i])
        i = (i + 1) % SINE_WAVE_STEPS
        #time.sleep(STEP_DELAY_MICROS / 1000000)  # Convert to seconds

def main():
    power_up()
    reset()  # Reset the DAC initially

    try:
        generate_sine_wave()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        power_down()
        GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

`

Your question is unclear. Try formatting as CODE; explain WHAT is connected and how you have enabled SPI in config.txt. You appear to be setting clock to 40MHz which exceeds the maximum. Why are you using RPi.GPIO?

Right now I am using AD5686 which is connected to the raspberry pi using SPI communication SPI0 (SCLK to CLK of DAC, CE1 to SYNC of DAC, MOSI to DIN of DAC and MISO to SDO of DAC). Also there is this power pin which is used to power up the board which contains this DAC (AD5686). This should be on for the DAC to work. And there is this reset pin which is in the DAC, which should be set low for 30ns such that the DAC output is reset to zero before giving the data. For these reasons I am using RPi.GPIO. And the DAC supports a maximum of 50Mhz that's why I have use 40Mhz.

Don't put details in comments EDIT your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
